# Which language for a quick GUI app + sqlite database CRUD (2-4 tables)

Tags: database, user-interface

Which language for quick GUI app + sqlite database CRUD (2-4 tables). Java, Python? (Please no jokes like VBasic), some reference, source code to look on?

added:

First idea:
1 database SQLite (Win) + client GUI app (Win)
clients table + orders table + others
import, export database
add, del, edit, etc. entries

Second idea:
1 hosted database (PostgreSQL ,MySQL) + web app client
clients table + orders table + others
import, export database
add, del, edit, etc. entries

Thinking about Django, RoR or local Java(Netbeans), Python(wxPython+ORM).

???

Comment: what's your target platform?!

Comment: I don't think that VB.Net would be a joke. Why do you think it would be?

Comment: I think by "GUI app" you're implying that you want an app for the desktop.  Your comment about VBasic implies that you're targeting Windows.  You may want to add these details to your question--might get you better responses.

Comment: I think its offensice to say VB.Net is a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby on Rails will do simple CRUD operations **very** easily - although doing more than that can be a little more complex (would require some reading about RoR's way of doing things). The latest version of Rails automatically uses sqlite databases, and in fact the whole database, and CRUD GUI code can be created with one command (`scaffold`).

If this is to be deployed then that can be a bit more difficult (although I hear that Capistrano is good) - but for local or intranet use then that's what I'd do.

Answer (score 4):

Try python with wxPython for UI programming. I suggest, that you look for an ORM mapper like SQLachemy.

Somebody suggested [dabo](http://dabodev.com/) which is made especially for your purpose, but I have no experience with it (yet). It works with wxPython and databases like SQLite.

Answer (score 4):

[Delphi](http://www.codegear.com). It's an ideal fit for this kind of desktop application, and there's a [SQLite wrapper available](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/a-simple-delphi-wrapper-for-sqlite-3).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you are most familiar with.

Or whatever have better set of ready to go components, so either Java (Netbeans/Matise + wizards) or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Need more info.  For in house or will you distribute?    Desktop or web-based?   If web-based, do you host it or will you have it hosted?

Then there's your personal goals.  Really, really do it quick, or let it be an opportunity to learn a language/technology you are curious about, like Ruby on Rails?  Linq?

Comment: Corey have good information but no solution, I really do not understand how you can accept this answer as the final one.

Comment: I agree. In the accepted answer, there are 7 sentences. 5 of them end with a question mark. They are all great questions that need to be ansered to provide a valid solution, but they are certainly not an answer in and of themselves.

Answer (score 2):

GUI development isn't much easier than with Tcl/tk. Also, Tcl has arguably the best interface to sqlite. If deployment is an issue there's definitely no language that can compete with tcl's tclkit/starkit/starpack packaging mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

[Xojo](https://www.xojo.com/) (formerly called [REALbasic](http://www.realsoftware.com/)), if you want to do a desktop app. The Personal edition comes with SQLite built in and is free on Linux, cheap on other platforms. It's a very clean OO language and reasonable IDE, about as productive as VB6 to work in but much cleaner.

I've been doing cross-platform development for about 15 years and REALbasic is now my tool of choice for straightforward database form apps, including an enterprise accounting system I'm currently working on.

I also am working in Swift, WPF/C#, C++ and Cocoa/Objective-C so I'm [not](https://github.com/AndyDentFree) just a "Basic-weanie" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Write a XulRunner app; this can run with Firefox 3.0.

http://developer.mozilla.org

Answer (score 0):

C# and WPF, it;s preatty easy and good to know (I've been playing with it for 1 week and fully wrote a twitter client in a few hours.

now Cocoa, and the interface Builder, that is a cool approach even for a simple app.

Answer (score 0):

If you were developing a web app I would suggest a scaffold-enabled site like **rails**, **django** or **ASP.NET MVC (dynamic data)**. If its a windows app, nothing beats the productivity and features of WPF/Silverlight, if so consider using [OrmLite](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/OrmLite), a POCO-driven lightweight ORM providing a set of useful extension methods around the common ADO.NET IDbConnection and IDbCommand interfaces. Using only convention and DataAnnotation attributes for configuration, it's effortlessly able to persist models with deep complex object graphs.

A live working example using Sqlite (with full source code) is available here:
http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Examples.Clients/Default.htm

There is also a complete end-to-end example (i.e. stand-alone, no other config required) on stackoverflow:
[xml to sql using linq and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106710/xml-to-sql-using-linq-and-c/2137249#2137249)