# xml to sql using linq and C#

Tags: sql, xml, linq

I have an xml file from an external system that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <Body>
        <Element1>
            <Element2 day="2009-10-18">
                <Element3 name="Joe">
                    <Element4 time="1">
                        <Element5 amount="0" price="16.58"/>
                    </Element4>
                </Element3>
                <Element3 name="Fred">
                    <Element4 time="5">
                        <Element5 amount="0" price="15.41"/>
                    </Element4>
                </Element3>
            </Element2>
        </Element1>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

I need to flatten this and put it into a sql table that will look like this.

```
day, name, time, amount, price
2009-10-18, Joe, 1, 0, 16.58
2009-10-18, Fred, 5, 0, 15.41
```

What is the best way to read the xml and insert it into my DB?  I've been playing with linq but without much sucess thus far.

Comment: The answer will depend greatly on whether or not you need the code to build the table structure, or just insert the data into a preexisting table.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I need to insert data into a pre existing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article is a good starting point for the basic idea.

[Extracting XML and Insert Bulk Data using LINQ to XML and LINQ to SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQ_FOR_OPERATIONS.aspx)

Adding a bit more here for those who might be interested in a similar solution.

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"myxml.xml");
            DataContext bt = new DataContext();

            var docxml = from c in doc.Elements("Envelope").Elements("Body").Elements("Element1").Elements("Element2").Elements("Element3")

                     select new mytable()
                     {
                         MyKey = Guid.NewGuid(),
                         day = Convert.ToDateTime(c.Parent.Attribute("day").Value),
                         name = c.FirstAttribute.Value,
                         time = Convert.ToInt32(c.Element("Element4").FirstAttribute.Value),
                         price = Convert.ToDecimal(c.Element("Element4").Element("Element5").Attribute("price").Value),
                         amount = Convert.ToDecimal(c.Element("Element4").Element("Element5").Attribute("amount").Value)

                     };

            bt.mytable.InsertAllOnSubmit(docxml);
            bt.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to insert that into a SQL Server table?? If so: what version of SQL Server?

You could easily just shred that apart in SQL Server using XQuery and insert the data into a table. Use something like:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS ns)
SELECT
    @input.value('(/ns:Envelope/ns:Body/ns:Element1/ns:Element2/@day)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'DayElement',
    node.el.value('(@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Name',
    node.el.value('(ns:Element4/@time)[1]', 'int') AS 'Time',
    node.el.value('(ns:Element4/ns:Element5/@amount)[1]', 'decimal(15,2)') AS 'Amount',
    node.el.value('(ns:Element4/ns:Element5/@price)[1]', 'decimal(15,2)') AS 'Price'
FROM
    @input.nodes('/ns:Envelope/ns:Body/ns:Element1/ns:Element2/ns:Element3') AS node(el)
```

and that gives you an output something like:

```
Day         Name    Time    Amount   Price
2009-10-18  Joe       1      0.00    16.58
2009-10-18  Fred      5      0.00    15.41
```

Of course, you could use that to supply the data to a `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable().....` statement and thus store your data into a table right away

Answer (score 0):

I have useful Open Source XLinq Extensions and other Utils that simplify parsing xml, persisting to the db, text serializing POCO classes, etc
The [complete example](http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/source/browse/trunk/Common/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceStack.Common.Tests/Xlinq/XlinqExtensionsTests.cs) is below:

```
    //source code for this example available at: 
    //http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/source/browse/trunk/Common/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceStack.Common.Tests/Xlinq/XlinqExtensionsTests.cs
    public class XmlData : IHasId<int>
    {
      [AutoIncrement]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Day { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public int Time { get; set; }
      public int Amount { get; set; }
      public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Insert_data_from_xml_into_db()
    {
      //OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance;
      OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance;

      var element2 = XElement.Parse(xml).AnyElement("Body").AnyElement("Element1").AnyElement("Element2");

      using (var db = ":memory:".OpenDbConnection())
      using (var dbCmd = db.CreateCommand())
      {
        dbCmd.CreateTable<XmlData>(true);
        foreach (var element3 in element2.AllElements("Element3"))
        {
          var xmlData = new XmlData {
            Day = element2.AnyAttribute("day").Value,
            Name = element3.AnyAttribute("name").Value,
            Time = int.Parse(element3.FirstElement().AnyAttribute("time").Value),
            Amount = int.Parse(element3.FirstElement().FirstElement().AnyAttribute("amount").Value),
            Price = decimal.Parse(element3.FirstElement().FirstElement().AnyAttribute("price").Value),
          };
          dbCmd.Insert(xmlData);
        }
        dbCmd.Select<XmlData>().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(StringSerializer.SerializeToString(x)));
      }
    }

//Prints out:
//{Id:1,Day:2009-10-18,Name:Joe,Time:1,Amount:0,Price:16.58}
//{Id:2,Day:2009-10-18,Name:Fred,Time:5,Amount:0,Price:15.41}
```

Comment: Interesting but I think the solution I added above is more simple and doesn't required additional components.

Comment: Agreed, but I consider it good practice when processing data to do it in code as its strongly-typed, easily testable, portable (i.e. non vendor-specific) and re-usable, etc.

The above example only works on specific versions of Sql Server (i.e. 2005+)

This is a complete working version in code with only 1 additional component.

Comment: Apologies, I was comparing it against the wrong answer. 

Yeah yours is in code (which is good) but not complete and requires a generated Linq2Sql model, configuration, existing table in Sql Server, etc - mine doesn't.